# Running tests from an ExternalProject as part of the main tests cmake target

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project that includes another project using `ExternalProject_Add`, for which the source is available at configure time:

```
ExternalProject_Add(projectB
   PREFIX abc
   SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/projectB"
   BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectB"
   INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

The external project gets built as part of the build for the parent project. I can run the tests for `projectB` if I run `make check` from `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectB`, but I want them to run with all the other tests with `make test`. How can I get the unit tests for `projectB` to run as part of the parent's test target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about getting a proper machine-readable test report for each individual test case in the external project then the following should work

```
add_test(projectB_tests
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectB" --target test
)
```

However, the drawback is that the XML generated by CTest will only indicate whether the test suite of `projectB` had a failure or not, but you need to read the entire output of the test run to find which particular test failed.

If you're not defining a [superbuild](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/) project though there should be no need to use `ExternalProject` in your scenario, a simple `add_subdirectory(projectB)` should work just fine, and the tests of `ProjectB` also are automatically added to your test target.

Comment: Thanks, that is enough for what I wanted to do, and worked after replacing the `--target test` with `--target check`. I found the `ExternalProject` was useful to avoid some configuration errors (one of those being the gtest included in `projectB` conflicting with the gtest in the parent project)

Answer (score 3):

I asked the CMake developers over at their Discourse about this before: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/testing-in-a-superbuild/1906

Ben Boeckel, one of the maintainers, replied with the following:

> I’ve done a hack for this in our superbuild infrastructure. You can likely adapt it for your project. The files in question:
>
> - [the logic](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/common-superbuild/-/blob/a843781c0a5d310f9b723eda311e8a789d82be76/CMakeLists.txt#L185-233)
> - [the trampoline](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/common-superbuild/-/blob/master/cmake/superbuild_testing_trampoline.cmake.in)
>
> The logic gathers the projects we want to test, extracts their binary directories and configures a `CTestTestfile.cmake` to do the work. It then uses the trampoline to do the actual `subdirs` calls for each project we’re interested in. This file is added to the list of files for CTest to include.